# Show that a 2k regular graph has a matching of size at least k-1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $H$ be a 2k-regular graph with $n=4k+1$ vertices (and thus $m=k(4k+1)$ edges).
Show that $H$ has at least k-1 independent edges (or that there exists a matching of size at least k-1 in $H$).
If the former is true, remove the k-1 independent edges from $H$.
Prove that the resulting graph $G$ will have a chromatic number of $\chi(G)=\Delta(G)+1$, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of $G$.

I only know of an upper bound for a maximum matching which is $2mn\over n+2m$ so in this case it is true that $k-1 \le {8k^2+2k \over 2k+1}$ but this is of no interest.
[This paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00373-007-0757-5) gives a lower bound for the maximum matching which solves the first problem, but i think it must be simpler than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are even $k$ independent edges.

First note that if we choose a pair of vertices (uniformly) at random, then the probability that they are connected with an edge is $1/2$. Now choose a vertex at random and randomly split the remaining $4k$ vertices into pairs (in other words, choose $2k$ different pairs of vertices at random); such splitting $\omega$ will be called *complete pairing*. Then the expectation of the number $X(\omega)$ of edges in those pairs is, by linearity,
$$
E[X] = 2k\cdot \frac{1}{2} = k. \tag{1}
$$
Then for some complete pairing $\omega$ it must hold $X(\omega)\ge k$ (yielding the above claim). Indeed, assuming on contrary that $X(\omega)\le k-1$ for any complete pairing $\omega$, we would get $E[X]\le k-1$, which contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: I can see your point, but can you explain how your answer definitely proves that, as opposed to giving some intuition on it's truth?

Comment: @ManoPlizzi, I've added more words. Is it clearer now?

Comment: No, it was quite clear before too. I mean can it be considered a proof when you are using propabilistic methods like sampling and expexted values? Can the result be considered absolutely true?

Comment: @ManoPlizzi, your question sounds quite insulting. But seriously, yes, of course, the probabilistic techniques are not less precise than any other mathematical tools. Moreover, they are often very efficient in the questions like this. If you still doubt the probabilistic method (which you shouldn't do), everything can be rewritten in just some sums over all complete pairings, changes of summation order etc.

Comment: I'm very sorry if i offended you, just not really familiar with probability. I'll go over it again and try to understand it better.

Comment: @ManoPlizzi, no offence taken. I would recommend to read Alon and Spencer's book "The probabilistic method".